# Base64 Android to String and get Hash md5

Tags: java, android, base64

есть bitmap который через этот метод

```
public static String convert(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
    return Base64.encodeToString(outputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.URL_SAFE );
}
```

должен вернуть base64 и сунуть его в json, потом из base64 получить md5 и снова положить в json,
основной код:

```
String fileName = selectedImage.getLastPathSegment();
            String base64 = ImageUtil.convert(bitmap);
            String hash = ImageUtil.md5(base64);
            Log.e(TAG, fileName);
            Log.e(TAG, base64);
            Log.e(TAG, hash);
            UserImage userImage = new UserImage(fileName, base64, hash);
```

метод получения md5

```
public static String md5(String s) {
    try {
        // Create MD5 Hash
        MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        digest.update(s.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        // Create Hex String
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i=0; i<messageDigest.length; i++)
            hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]));

        return hexString.toString();
    }catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

ответ от сервера:

```
Hash validation error. Expected: ab6d68e277fbd8a7621fbd7ca8d168, actual: 8dbfc0c5479f862387e0327f19837deb{json...
```

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `digest.update(s.getBytes());` и получать массив байт через `messageDigest[] = digest.digest(s.getBytes());`

Comment: не помогло это решение

Comment: А может сервер хочет хеш оригинальной картинки, а не закодированной в Base64? И ещё замечание: `Integer.toHexString` отбрасывает незначимые нули(`0f` -> `f`), для хеш-сумм это критично, поищите правильный пример.

Comment: как я могу взять хеш оригинальной картинки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего сервер хочет хеш оригинального изображения, а не закодированного в `Base64`.
Тогда сделаем так:

`ImageUtil`:

```
public static byte[] compress(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}

public static String convert(byte[] imageBytes) {
    return Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.URL_SAFE );
}

public static String md5(byte[] srcBytes) {
    try {
        // Create MD5 Hash
        MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        digest.update(srcBytes);
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        // Create Hex String
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i=0; i<messageDigest.length; i++) {
            String hb = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
            if (hb.length() == 1) {
                hexString.append('0');
            }
            hexString.append(hb);
        }

        return hexString.toString();
    }catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

---

Используем:

```
String fileName = selectedImage.getLastPathSegment();
byte[] imageBytes = ImageUtil.compress(bitmap);
String base64 = ImageUtil.convert(imageBytes);
String hash = ImageUtil.md5(imageBytes);
Log.e(TAG, fileName);
Log.e(TAG, base64);
Log.e(TAG, hash);
UserImage userImage = new UserImage(fileName, base64, hash);
```

**P.S.** за правильность формирования строки `md5` не ручаюсь - мог ошибиться

Comment: помогло, только стоить ставить Base64.DEFAULT а не URL_SAFE

Comment: Это нюансы требований вашего конкретного сервера, о которых мне ничего не известно. Что делать если ответ вам помог: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7025/11515